# Axis2 ByteArray Web Service Return as String

Tags: java, android, web-services, arrays, apache-axis

I am developing an Android application which suppose to call Axis2 Web Service (already implemented and running) where the previous developer made in such a way that Byte[] is the common form of passing Object around. Suppose there is a need to invoke web service in the Axis2 which should return List, the web service will convert the instance into Byte[] and return the Byte[], where the client will convert it back.

Here is the snippet from the service:

```
public byte[] getMyPersonList() throws Exception {
    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(new List<Person>());
    return (baos.toByteArray());
}
```

In the client (not my android application but the existing desktop application which are developed by the same people making the web service)

```
byte[] buffer = (byte[]) serviceClient.invokeBlocking(methodName,
            new Object[] {}, new Class[] { byte[].class })[0];
java.io.ObjectInputStream ois = new java.io.ObjectInputStream(
            new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
return (List<Person>) ois.readObject();
```

The invokeBlocking() method seems to automatically convert the returned value from the service automatically back to byte[], but I am having trouble doing the same thing in my application.

This is what the return value looks like when I invoke the service manually over browser:

`<return>
rO0ABXNyABNqYXZhLnV0aWwuQXJyYXlMaXN0eIHSHZnHYZ0DAAFJAARzaXpleHAAAAAJdwQAAAAKc3IAJ3dvcmtmbG9.......................
</return>`

And what I have done so far is to directly get the return as string and use getBytes():

```
byte [] soapReturnBytes = resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyAsString("return").getBytes();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
myPersonList= (List<Person>) ois.readObject();
```

But I received stream corrupted error which could mean that it simply not the same content when I convert it back.

So my question is:

1. When returning Byte[], what does Axis2 engine do to convert the values to fit it into the SOAP return
2. What are the methods of converting this 'stringified' value back to Byte[], in case I can't do anything about the web service (no modification on the web service)

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

As suggested, I am using a decoder to get the result, however still no luck:

```
String result = resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyAsString("return");           
byte[] soapReturnBytes = Base64.decode(result, Base64.DEFAULT);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(soapReturnBytes);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
orgs = (List<Person>) ois.readObject();
```

I still received the same error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format: 0
```

Any suggestion? *getting frustrated*

EDIT 2:

I created another service which returns String as byte[], and in my Android application I received the byte[] and convert it back to the original String. So perhaps it has something to do with the way I am using the Stream to convert my Object <=> byte [].

Comment: Can you copy the string Axis2 service returned and paste it into your decoder to see what happens? Either service doesn't return proper value or your client doesn't read that string appropriately.

Comment: There is still one thing unclear - can you add `System.out.println(resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyAsString("return"));` and compare the output with content of the web service response? If matches, then the problem is probably in the process of (de)serialization.

Comment: What does it show the output parameter type when you hit the webservice wsdl file in the web browser ??

Comment: I've built many apps that consume data from services, restful services Would it be too hard to return json or xml instead? I know it's not an legitimate answer to the question itself, but it's a direction you might want to go?

Answer (score 1):

> When returning Byte[], what does Axis2 engine do to convert the values to fit it into the SOAP return

The Java type `byte[]` is mapped to the XML Schema type `xsd:base64Binary`. The transformation is called Base64 encoding.

> What are the methods of converting this 'stringified' value back to Byte[], in case I can't do anything about the web service (no modification on the web service)

You need to use a Base64 decoder. There are numerous Java implementations available, e.g. Commons Codec.

Comment: I have tried using the Base64 Decoder from Android utilities, but the stream is still corrupted when I convert my byte[] to InputStream. I have updated my question.